# Views#3 custom handler error

Tags: 7, views

I'm learning how to implement a custome Views 3 field handler.

Using the following handler code:

```
class views_handler_filter_sub_nodes extends views_handler_field_custom{

    function options_form(&$form, &$form_state){

        drupal_set_message('My customer handler is responding', 'warning');

        parent::options_form(&$form, &$form_state);
    }
}
```

I get the following error, repeated twice:

```
Deprecated function: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in _registry_check_code() (line 3119 of /var/www/My-Site/includes/bootstrap.inc)
```

I have removed the **&** symbols from the arguments. The errors go away but so do all the configuration fields in my View component, as illustrated below:

[image]

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Shouldn't you be extending a filter handler rather than a field handler?

Comment: @Clive: Nice catch. As I'm learning how it's done, the views_handler_filter_sub_nodes() function name is incorretly named but the functionality is very much a field and NOT a filter. Unless there's something else you noticed and I missed???

Comment: I'm not at the computer so this is a guess - try returning `parent::options_form` rather than just invoking it. Failing that, install the advanced help module and look under Help -> Views, I think there's a field handler code example in there

Answer (score 0):

Huh? It's been a year and no one has found the error referred to by the message ("Call-time pass-by-reference").

Leave

```
function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
```

unchanged.

And change this:

```
parent::options_form(&$form, &$form_state);
```

to:

```
parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
```

and your error should go away.

---

Briefly (for those who are new to user defined functions, as it relates to this issue)...

**Function declaration**

A function's arguments are defined in the function's declaration (the line that begins with the `function` keyword). They are a list of PHP variables the function expects to receive from the caller (see  [Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)  in the PHP manual for more information). The function declaration determines how many arguments are expected, their datatypes, whether they are required or optional, and whether they are passed by reference or not, among other things.

You have surely noticed the `$form` and `$form_state` variables used in lots of [form-api](/questions/tagged/form-api) function declarations, sometimes with and sometimes without a preceding **&**. Each **&** tells the function that that argument will be passed to it *by reference*. This means the function does not receive a copy of the variable from the caller (as usual), but a pointer to it.

A function may change the contents of references directly from within the function, while a copy is private to the function and must be `return`ed, if the function want its changes to be available to the function that called it (of course, the caller must know what to do with the returned data). Any changes made to reference variables remain after the function ends.

**Function execution**

When a function is called/executed, the **&** MUST be omitted, otherwise you get the aforementioned "Call-time pass-by-reference" error. The function declaration determines if it's a reference, not the caller.